# How to insert data into a Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have this code

```
$loginData = $this->_request->getPost();
$loginForm = new Form_Login(); // extends Zend_Form
```

and I don't need to check if the form is valid.

How can insert *$loginData* into *$loginForm*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$loginForm->populate($loginData);
```